# How Can I Find Whether My Dataset is balanced or not?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created loan risk prediction python machine learning model for Predict whether borrower will able to pay bank loan or not. My model is working perfectly fine with 78% accuracy. However my professor told me that first I have to check whether my dataset is balanced or not and (  Apply SMOTE from imblearn library if it's not. ). the main issue is I don't know how to check is balanced or not. Please let me know if anyone know how to check.

Dataset Link :- https://www.kaggle.com/omkar5/dataset-for-bank-loan-prediction?select=credit_train.csv
( this Dataset I used to for create model )

Comment: Check if there is 50:50 ratio for the classes in your target variable. Here's a sample kernel for you on how to balance the data: https://www.kaggle.com/adityakadiwal/heart-failure-prediction-smote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple words, you need to check if there is an imbalance in the classes present in your target variable.

For example:
[image]

If you check the ratio between DEATH_EVENT=1 and DEATH_EVENT=0, it is 2:1 which means our dataset is imbalanced.

To balance, we can either oversample or undersample the data.
Undersampling in this case would be to remove 100 rows where the DEATH_EVENT=0 for 1:1 ratio but we would lose a lot of data in the process.

On the other hand, SMOTE can help us generate rows for the minority class.
You can do that using the following code:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
smote = SMOTE()
X, y = smote.fit_resample(X, y)

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X), pd.DataFrame(y)], axis=1)
```

Now coming to the "high" accuracy of your model, since most of the data belongs to the majority class 0, just predicting 0 for all rows should give me a high accuracy and hence you should check for other performance metrics like recall, precision and f1-score as well.

Comment: Bro can you please tell me at which stage I have to balance my dataset if it's imbalanced. I mean should I have to balance data after the "data slicing" operation or before.

Comment: You can perform this just before you do the Train-test split.